# Browser bar URL changes itself for S3 website

Tags: url, amazon-s3, http-redirect, static-site

I've set up an s3-hosted static website using the [AWS walkthrough](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html). I've also followed the walkthrough to get a domain name using route53 that forwards to the site (by creating a RecordSet with type A-IPV4 and specifying the alias as the s3 bucket). This sort of works. I can see the content fine - entering `mything.com` into the browser's url bar brings up the correct page.

But the browser's url bar automatically changes to `http://mything.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com`. I don't want that - I want the url bar to keep displaying `mything.com`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The way you are wanting it to work is exactly how it is *supposed* to work.  It's not clear, from the currently-available information, why it would be working as you describe, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've fixed it.
Problem was that, as per the walkthrough, I'd set up two S3 buckets called `mything.com` and `www.mything.com`. Then I set `www.mything.com` to redirect to the other bucket. The problem was that in the AWS redirect field, I'd entered the other bucket's *endpoint*, rather than just its name. In a browser, when I went to `www.mything.com` I was getting a 301 redirect to the full s3 endpoint. In chrome 47, the 301 redirect was cached and was then also applying (slightly intermittently) even when I entered `mything.com` into the url bar. After fixing the redirect in the aws console, I needed to kill my recent browsing history in chrome to get rid of the cached 301 redirects.

Comment: @thund I am facing this exact same problem. However I already had only the name of the bucket in the redirect field. Any idea of what could be causing it to fail anyway?

Comment: @Fane Sorry, no idea. I went through this process 2 years ago so I don't remember anything except what I wrote in the answer above. However, I've been using this approach ever since and never had a problem with it, so it seems pretty reliable.